# Flutter: Drawer widget refresh the page when pressing the same tab

Tags: flutter

I am trying to refresh the page by pressing the same drawer tab. If I keep passing index 1 it prevent me to create new FirstWidget(). Is it possible to refresh the page by pressing the same drawer tab?

Changing page function:

```
void _selectTab(int index) {
    setState(() {
      switch (index) {
        case 1:
          widget.currentPage = new FirstWidget();
          break;
        case 2:
          widget.currentPage = new SecondWidget();
          break;
      }
    });
}
```

Scaffold body:

`body: widget.currentPage`